# Prove $\{0 \bmod 2, 0 \bmod 3, 1 \bmod 4, 1 \bmod 6, 11 \bmod 12\}$is a covering system

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to figure out why $\{0 \bmod 2, 0 \bmod 3, 1 \bmod 4, 1 \bmod 6, 11 \bmod 12\}$ is a covering system. Is there a neat way to prove it?

Answer (score 2):

Write out what all of the equivalence classes are modulo the LCM of the moduli. In this case, $0\bmod 2$ is the same thing as $0,2,4,6,8$, and $10\bmod 12$, $0\bmod3$ is the same thing as $0,3,6$, and $9\bmod 12$, $1\bmod4$ is the same thing as $1,5$, and $9\bmod12$. Add to that $11\bmod12$ and...

Unfortunately, you seem to be missing $7\bmod12$, so I don't think this is actually a covering system?

This appears to have been found in a lovely little paper, but was reproduced here with a typo! You want to include $1\bmod 6$.

Comment: I came across this system of congruence in an article and it does not include 7 mod 12. The article is here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04372.pdf

Comment: @Jingting931015 Ah, you have a typo in your post. You lost the $1\bmod 6$ class.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Thanks for making the correction

Comment: In your article:  "Each of the moduli in
C
divides 12, so we can check that
C
covers the integers by verifying that
each residue class modulo 12 is a subset of one of the residue c
lasses in
C"  That's how you verify it.  In my answer I did that explicitely.

Answer (score 1):

If $n \equiv 0,2,4,6,8,10 \pmod {12}$ then $n \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ and is covered.

If $n\equiv 1,5,9 \pmod {12}$ then $n\equiv 1\pmod {4}$ and $n$ is covered.

If $n \equiv 0, 3, 6, 9 \pmod{12}$ then $n\equiv 0 \pmod {3}$ and $n$ is covered.

If $n \equiv 1,7 \pmod {12}$ then $n \equiv 1 \pmod {6}$ and $n$ is covered.

If $n \equiv 11 \pmod{12}$ then it is covered.

So $n$ is covered if $n \equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 \pmod {12}$.  And all natural numbers fall into one of those categories.  So all natural numbers are covered.