# Why does there not exist a particular finite set of congruences that forms a partition of the set of integers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, set-partition

There is a paragragh that I saw in an article and could not really understand. The article is [Covering Systems of Congruences](https://www.jstor.org/stable/30044163?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), J. Fabrykowski and T. Smotzer, Mathematics Magazine Vol. 78, No. 3 (Jun., 2005), pp. 228-231, DOI: 10.2307/30044163. It starts by discussing problem 9 from the 2002 American Invitational Mathematics Examination (AIME):

> PROBLEM. Harold, Tanya, and Ulysses paint a very long fence. Harold starts with the first picket and paints every $h$th picket; Tanya starts with the second picket and paints every $t$th picket; and Ulysses starts with the third picket and paints every $u$th picket. If every picket gets painted exactly once, find all possible triples $(h,t,u)$.

After presenting the solution, the article goes on to say:

> One can generalize the AIME problem and ask whether there exists a finite set of congruences, with all moduli distinct and greater than or equal to $2$, that forms a partition of the set of integers. This turns out to be impossible. Relaxing the assumption about *partitioning* the integers, one can look for finite sets of congruences such that every integer belongs to *at least one* of them."

Can anyone help explain why the first part is impossible?

Comment: By the way, if you have access to the full article then it would be very useful to know what reference [4] is. I can only see the preview of the first page.

Answer (score 1):

This is far from a full answer, but it gives a taste of how strong the constraints are.

Suppose we have $k$ congruences of the form $x \equiv a_i \pmod {m_i}$ where the $m_i$ are distinct and greater than $1$, and $0 < a_i \le m_i$ is the smallest natural number covered by the congruence. Further suppose that we've chosen a minimum set of congruences: i.e. there is no solution with fewer than $k$ congruences.

Consider two distinct congruences $x \equiv a_i \pmod {m_i}$ and $x \equiv a_j \pmod {m_j}$. We require $a_i \not\equiv a_j \pmod {\gcd(m_i, m_j)}$ to avoid collisions. (This follows from the Chinese remainder theorem, and is necessary and sufficient for non-intersection). Note that this implies that $\gcd(m_i, m_j) > 1$, so no two moduli are coprime.

Since a congruence with modulus $m_i$ covers $\frac{1}{m_i}$ of the integers, we must have $$\sum_i \frac{1}{m_i} = 1$$ so we have a partition of unity in Egyptian fractions. Combined with non-intersection, this is necessary and sufficient to partition the natural numbers.

**Lemma**: no non-trivial proper subset of the congruences is reducible to a single congruence. Suppose that we had a set of congruences $x \equiv a_i \pmod{m_i}$ which partition $x \equiv \alpha \pmod\mu$. Then clearly $m_i \equiv 0 \pmod\mu$ and $a_i \equiv \alpha \pmod\mu$, and the congruences $x \equiv \frac{a_i - \alpha}\mu \pmod {\frac{m_i}\mu}$ partition the natural numbers. But we started from a proper subset of the congruences, so this contradicts the assumption that $k$ is minimum.

**Corollary**: there is no $c > 1$ which is a common factor of all of the moduli. (Proof: if there were, one proper subset of the congruences would be reducible to $x \equiv 1 \pmod c$ and another to $x \equiv 2 \pmod c$. Since they can't both consist of a single congruence with modulus $c$, one of them is non-trivial, contradicting the lemma).

**Corollary**: none of the moduli is a prime power, for then that prime must be a common factor of all the moduli.

**Corollary**: $k \ge 19$. (Proof: we have to sum the reciprocals of the first 19 non-prime-powers to exceed $1$. Of course, those 19 numbers don't satisfy the no-pair-coprime constraint, and the sum of their reciprocals isn't exactly unity...).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there are finite distinct covering systems. See the system below:

$0(3), 0(4), 0(5), 1(6), 1(8), 2(10), 11(12), 1(15), 14(20), 5(24), 8(30), 6(40), 58(60), 26(120) $

Answer (score -1):

The answer is yes.  There are several.

This question gives one example: [Prove {0 mod 2, 0 mod 3, 1 mod 4, 1 mod 6, 11 mod 12} is a covering system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016641/prove-0-mod-2-0-mod-3-1-mod-4-1-mod-6-11-mod-12-is-a-covering-system)

$0 \mod 2, 0 \mod 3, 1\mod 4, 1\mod 6, 11 \mod 12$.

This paper is all about them https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04372.pdf